# var text = $html.find("script type='application/ld+json':contains('sameAs')").text();

Tags: javascript

```
var text = $html.find("script type='application/ld+json':contains('sameAs')").text();
```

i didn't understanding what does this means? i haven't seen this before . Can you tel me where this is used and why. If you have any idea then tell me.

Comment: That probably doesn't work. What is the output?

Comment: Would be used to pull the JSON from the text in the script tag. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50351217/extract-json-from-html-source-in-javascript/50351398#50351398

Comment: Please put the code in the question, not just the title, so it can be formatted readably.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's just wrong. It probably should be:

```
var text = $html.find("script[type='application/ld+json']:contains('sameAs')").text();
```

The first part of the selector `script[type='application/ld+json']` will match all elements in `$html` like:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">...</script>
```

The `:contains('sameAs')` modifier then restricts the result to elements that have the string `sameAs` somewhere in the contents.